# Force Unique Value During Update, without a good join key

Tags: t-sql

I have a table "MyTable" with 3 columns:

- FilePath
- FileName
- Status

My Table row example:

```
FilePath | FileName | Status
c:\temp  | Null     | 30
c:\temp  | Null     | 30
c:\temp  | Null     | 30
c:\temp  | Null     | 30
c:\temp  | a.csv    | 40
c:\temp  | b.csv    | 40
c:\temp  | c.csv    | 40
c:\temp  | d.csv    | 40
```

I want to update rows with the FileName is null, with rows where FileName has value.

Now the following query will update the nulls with the same value for all.

**I need to force the update to select a unique value per row during the update**

```
UPDATE  t1
SET t1.FileName = t2.FileName
FROM MyTable t1
JOIN MyTable t2 ON t1.FilePath = t2.FilePath
```

The current update will give the following result:

```
FilePath | FileName | Status
c:\temp  | a.csv    | 30
c:\temp  | a.csv    | 30
c:\temp  | a.csv    | 30
c:\temp  | a.csv    | 30
c:\temp  | a.csv    | 40
c:\temp  | b.csv    | 40
c:\temp  | c.csv    | 40
c:\temp  | d.csv    | 40
```

And what I need is:

```
FilePath | FileName | Status
c:\temp  | a.csv    | 30
c:\temp  | b.csv    | 30
c:\temp  | c.csv    | 30
c:\temp  | d.csv    | 30
c:\temp  | a.csv    | 40
c:\temp  | b.csv    | 40
c:\temp  | c.csv    | 40
c:\temp  | d.csv    | 40
```

Comment: Can you just delete the rows with NULL filename and then do something like this: `insert into MyTable (filepath, filename, status) select filepath, filename, 30 from MyTable where filepath='c:\temp' and status=40`?

Comment: Is the order supposed to be alphabetical by `FileName`? It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: What is the purpose / role of the `Status` field in your example? You don't seem to use it all. If it is irrelevant to the question, please remove it to reduce confusion.

Comment: Please clarify in the question the role of `FilePath` field. It is only mentioned in your query. Please say explicitly how it should be used. If you add few more sample rows with different `FilePath` it would help.  Please also clarify what should happen if number of NULL rows is different to the number of non-NULL rows. Again, add few rows to the data to illustrate two variants: when there are 6 NULL rows and 4 non-NULL; when there are 2 NULL rows and 4 non-NULL.

Comment: No, I cannot delete the rows. The rows and columns provided are just a sample, there are thousands of them.

Comment: Well the Filepath is the location where the FileName resides.
The number of rows and columns provided in the sample are just a small number. There are thousands of rows.

Comment: The status column is used to classify the status of the file. 
Why would I use the Status field in a query trying to do a Join?

Answer (score 1):

On the wild assumptions that you are using a reasonably modern version of SQL Server and that you would like the `FileName` pattern to start anew and repeat as needed for each status that has NULL `FileName` values:

```
-- Sample data.
declare @MyTable as Table ( Id Int Identity, FilePath VarChar(16), FileName VarChar(16), Status Int );
insert into @MyTable ( FilePath, FileName, Status ) values
  ( 'c:\temp', null, 30 ),
  ( 'c:\temp', null, 30 ),
  ( 'c:\temp', null, 30 ),
  ( 'c:\temp', null, 30 ),
  ( 'c:\temp', 'a.csv', 40 ),
  ( 'c:\temp', 'b.csv', 40 ),
  ( 'c:\temp', 'c.csv', 40 ),
  ( 'c:\temp', 'd.csv', 40 ),
  ( 'c:\temp', null, 50 ),
  ( 'c:\temp', null, 60 ),
  ( 'c:\temp', null, 60 ),
  ( 'c:\temp', null, 60 ),
  ( 'c:\temp', null, 60 ),
  ( 'c:\temp', null, 60 ),
  ( 'c:\temp', null, 60 ),
  ( 'c:\temp', null, 60 );
select * from @MyTable;

-- Update the   null   values.
with
  FileNames as (
    select FileName, Row_Number() over ( order by FileName ) - 1 as RN
      from @MyTable
      where FileName is not NULL ),
  NullNames as (
    select Id, Row_Number() over ( partition by Status order by FileName ) - 1 as RN
      from @MyTable
      where FileName is NULL )
  update MT
    set FileName = FN.FileName
    from @MyTable as MT inner join
      NullNames as NN on NN.Id = MT.Id inner join
      FileNames as FN on FN.RN = NN.RN % ( select count(42) from FileNames );
select * from @MyTable;
```

Comment: It is very natural to use 42 in the `Count()`